# Getting sometimes double POST request to IIS 10 webserver

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-post, iis-10

Since we migrated to an Amazon EC instance we're getting sometimes double POST requests to our SaaS application. I have no idea where this is coming from and why this is happening. I've been searching and looking at different options, but can't find the root cause. We migrated from IIS7 to IIS10 on a Windows Server 2022 Datacenter.

Here is an example of an SEQ logging session at 1 client:

[SEQ Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vryz0.png)

You can see the endpoint was requested multiple times (= OK), but there is also a double POST request at 18:19:41 and 18:18:27. This is logged from within the ASP.NET MVC controller. If I look at the IIS 10 logs, I see the same thing. So the request seems to be initiated from the browser and not doubled in the pipeline.

The MVC controller looks something like this (simplified):

```
if (ViewData.ModelState.IsValid){
    try
    {
       NHibernateSession.Current.Transaction.Begin();

       foreach (var item in deliveryDTosToSave){
          var delivery = new Delivery
                        {
                            //copying over the DTO to the delivery
                        };

          _deliveryRepository.SaveNew(delivery, userCode, item.Index);
       }
       NHibernateSession.Current.Transaction.Commit();
       
       return RedirectToAction("Add", "Delivery", new { tab, pharmacyId });
   }
   catch (RuleException ex)
   {
      NHibernateSession.Current.Transaction.Rollback();

   }
}
```

On the client-side, the javascript to submit is something like this:

```
$('#formDeliveries').submit(function () {
   if (!canSubmit) {return false;}
   $("#loading").show();
   canSubmit = false;
});
```

Things I looked for:

- user double-clicking on the submit button: we've blocked this through JS after initial submit. I interviewed several users, and they are not double-clicking.
- bug in browser: last user I logged in used Edge 107, which is recent. I can't find anything on the matter
- HTTPS redirects: the website is HTTPS-only and users have to be authenticated to use it.
- HTTP/3 fall-back scenario's: could be possible as we've enabled HTTP/3 when migrating to Amazon. However users are seeing this behaviour only sometimes and not always from the same browser.

We've tried to simulate the behaviour, but cannot find it. We've logged into the users computer and tried to simulated it while looking at the network requests through the developers utils, but cannot simulate it. I was hoping to see it happening live, so we can rule out any javascript items. If the network log in developer tools shows only 1 POST, it probably has to do something with the IIS pipeline.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to use failed request tracking to view the request process and check whether there are details of the post request.